# Audit Trigger Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, triggers

How do audit triggers normally affect performance of SQL inserts / updates?  If I create a trigger which updates the record being updated / inserted in a table, by selecting a value from another table, would this normally affect performance?  The database in question is a data warehouse, and it would typically need to process several thousand inserts / updates within a few minutes.

Comment: It depends on many factor, in special that select performance and insert. The only way to be sure is testing and trying to tune the operations inside the trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: yes. By how much is the question and it's impossible to know without testing. If you're concerned about it, try to do it asynchronously with change data capture and something to process that data.